# Validate a Boolean expression with brackets in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, boolean, boolean-logic

I want to validate a string in javascript that contains a Boolean expression with brackets. The string should only contain numbers `1-9`, `()`, `OR` , `AND`.

Examples of good strings:

> "1 AND 2"
>
> "2 OR 4"
>
> "4 AND (3 OR 5)"

I am not sure if Regular Expression are flexible enough for this task. Is there a nice short way of achieving this in javascript ?

Comment: .NET regex is quite powerful and can match balanced constructs, too. What have you tried? Why do you say you are writing it in C# but tagged the question with a JS tag?

Comment: title says in JavaScript and content says in C#.

Comment: sorry, i edited content of question

Comment: validate -> whether the syntax is correct or not. evaluate -> whether the result is true or not. which one you want?

Answer (score 3):

While regex alone isn't powerful enough for this task (because JS regex can't handle nested braces), it's an easy task with a little help from Javascript.

Since we can't deal with nested braces, we'll deal with the braces one at a time until none are left. The pattern `\(\d\)|\d (?:AND|OR) \d|\d` will match an expression of the form `(X)` or `X AND/OR Y` or `X` (where `X` and `Y` are digits). We replace all occurrences of this pattern with `1` (or any other valid expression in your boolean language), until the pattern no longer matches. If after all replacements are done the string is `"1"`, then it was a valid expression.

```
function validate(expression){
  const pattern = /\(\d\)|\d (?:AND|OR) \d|\d/g;
  while (true){
    const replaced = expression.replace(pattern, "1");

    // if the expression has been reduced to "1", it's valid
    if (replaced == "1") return true;

    // if the pattern didn't match, it's invalid
    if (replaced == expression) return false;

    // otherwise, continue replacing
    expression = replaced;
  }
}
```

Note that the regex doesn't allow for extra spaces.

Comment: i tried your partern in https://regex101.com/r/jgx2Qc/1 but not enough. I want logic expression at least: 4 AND (3 OR 5) AND (1 OR 6) or more

Comment: @Tommy1209 Fixed a bug in the regex. Please don't ignore the code in my answer. It validates `4 AND (3 OR 5) AND (1 OR 6)` just fine.

Comment: Almost working, but allows mismatched brackets e.g var x = validate ('1 AND (2 OR 3') returns true, but is invalid

Comment: @hamayoun Fixed. The new regex is not only correct, but also much more readable!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can use the following.
replace 'AND/OR/NOT' with '&&/||/!'.
use `eval` to evaluate it.

Careful because eval is a powerful function

```js
var string = "0 AND 2";
var string1 = "0 OR 2";
var string2 = "NOT 0";
evaluate(string);
evaluate(string1);
evaluate(string2);
function evaluate(string){
  string=string.replace(/AND/g,'&&');
  string=string.replace(/OR/g,'||');
  string=string.replace(/NOT/g,'!');
  console.log(eval(string));
}
```

Comment: OP said _validate_, not _evaluate_. Though I guess this would throw an error if the expression is invalid.

Comment: @Rawing the question has lots of mistakes and I assume OP want evaluate. I added a comment in question and will take action accordingly. Thanks for noticing me about it.