# Regular expression for boolean expression almost working

Tags: regex, apex

My regular expression is:

`(?:^ *)?(?:\\(*|())[0-9](?: +(?:AND|OR) +(?:\\(|[0-9]))?(?: *\\)|\\1)`

And I am trying to use this as a test string:

`1 AND 2 OR (3 AND 4 OR (2 AND 1))`

If I replace all matches it finds, I end up with `1 OR (1 OR 1)` when the final string should just be 1 (replacing each match with 1).

I think it is the +(?:\(|[0-9])) part. The regex seems to disregard instances of `number JOIN (number`

I pulled this regex from the second answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528748/validate-a-boolean-expression-with-brackets-in-javascript-regex)

And the comments say it is supposed to find situations of `3 AND (1` etc... but it is not when I use it.

Does anyone know how I might modify this regular expression to properly group a boolean expression?

Comment: _almost working_ ... I would hate to see what the regex would look like for more deeply nested content.  In general, regex isn't a good choice to handle nested content, like arithmetic expressions.  Use a parser instead.

Comment: You should tag your question with a language or tool. Never copy / paste a regex without understanding it.

Comment: The answer I got it from explained what each line was doing. I was trying to modify it to get it to work, but it fails to correctly group the parts of the boolean expression. And language isn't entirely relevant here as I was just looking for help on the regular expression

Comment: Knowing the language or regex engine directly is highly relevant. Matching recursively is a feature that is supported by a few regex engines only.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon why do you claim so? regex does parse nested structures

Comment: @Onyambu A stateless lexer cannot parse nested structures, how would it know how many parentheses it has to close? Some languages have stateful regex engines, but they are technically no longer regex, they are *extended regex*.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon its interesting to see that you have indicated that this is possible in *extended regex* well that's the reason revo did ask to know the language OP is trying to use.

Comment: @Onyambu I had deleted my initial comment because I did indeed find that other comments covered that fact adequatly

Comment: This is in Apex, which is essentially handling regex as Java would. But most likely the expression WOULD handle it just fine if Apex handled regular expressions recursively, but it seems not to. So, handling this through regex may now be out of the question.

Comment: can you try something like `(\(?(?:\d (?:AND|OR) (?:(?1)|\d))\)?)`